# Google Cloud Vision Working on localhost, but not on Google Cloud Hosted WordPress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am writing a WordPress Plugin which uses Google Cloud Vision V1 ImageAnnotatorClient. I use the labelDetection, landmarkDetection, faceDetection and logoDetection methods.

My website is hosted on the Google Cloud.

When I run on my localhost, everything works great.  When I upload to the Google Cloud site, the labelDetection works, but landmarkDetection, faceDetection and logoDetection fail, showing a 500 internal server error.

I have verified that the /vendor files are the same on localhost and online. I have compared wp-config files, and they are comparable.

I have implemented under a try / catch structure and when it fails I get nothing other than the 500 error.

I have tried closing the client and reopening; same results.  I have changed the order; same results; I have called labels twice and both work.

Here is the pertinent part of the code:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $annotate = new Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient(['credentials'=>__DIR__ .'key.json']);
    $reread = file_get_contents($file);
    
    // works on localhost and google cloud hosted site
    $responseLabel = $annotate->labelDetection($reread);
    $labels = $responseLabel->getLabelAnnotations();
    if ($labels) {
        // do something
    } 
    
    // works on localhost only
    $responseLandmark = $annotate->landmarkDetection($reread);
    $landmarks = $responseLandmark->getLandmarkAnnotations();
    if ($landmarks) {
        // do something
    }
    
    // works on localhost only
    $responseFace = $annotate->faceDetection($reread);
    $faces = $responseFace->getFaceAnnotations();
    if ($faces) {
        // do something
    }
    
    // works on localhost only
    $responseLogo = $annotate->logoDetection($reread);
    $logos = $responseLogo->getLogoAnnotations();
    if ($logos) {
        // do something
    }   
    $annotate->close();
```

I am not sure where to look next.  Any help would be appreciated.